# Laravel - CSRF is not matching with session token

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am trying to submit one form and login one user and it seems to work fine in localhost, but when I upload this code onto a live server then the Token is not working.

I have checked that the CSRF token and session token value is not same.

Also the post request is not working so I have added the route in except `VerifyCsrfToken` now the post request is working but after login the user session is not working

```
if (Session::token() != $request->get('_token'))
{
   echo 'Not Match';exit;
}
```

Above the result shows me no match .

I have regenerated the key on the server, also I had provided the permission to storage folder.

Cache data has been cleared but the authectioncation is not working it doesn't work.

```
<form class="login-form js-login-frm" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.login-post') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group" title="{{__('username_or_email_address')}}">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></span>
                        <input class="form-control" autofocus type="text" id="email_address" placeholder="{{ __('username_or_email_address') }}" name="login"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group" title="{{__('enter_password')}}">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                        <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" placeholder="{{ __('enter_password') }}" name="password"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button class="btn-del btn-5 btn-5a fa fa-lock login-btn" type="submit" id="login_btn">
            <span>{{ __('login') }}</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In My controller

```
$remember = $request->remember ? true : false;
$auth = Auth::guard('web')->attempt([
  'email' => $request->login,
  'password' => $request->password,
  'is_active' => 1
], $remember);
```

This code is working fine but the user doesn't get redirected to the dashboard page it redirect to login page again.

Can anyone help with the login the user in the system, and redirect to proper route.

Answer (score 0):

In a test environment the CSRF token is not checked in the middleware. Replace `{{ csrf_field() }}` with `@csrf` and you should be fine. Have a look at the source code of the generated login page.

Comment: Not working, It generates the token but the session::token and value of  _token mismatch

Comment: You mentioned a regenerated application key. Did you ran config:cache? I heard about your issue before. It had something to do with colliding cookies. Sounds strange, I know. It happened when they uploaded the site with the same app key. Does the same appear on another browser?

Comment: Not sure what clear:all is. If your app keys are different on test and prod and it doesn't work, it is most probably a caching issue somewhere. Try to run `php artisan view:clear` and `composer dump-autoload -o` on the server. The latter will optimize your PSR4 classmap.

Comment: If you used the `env()` helper somewhere out of the /config files it won't pick it up on production. You have to replace it with `config()`. This is probably not the cause of your issue, but I like to mention it as a remote reason.